# Delete Specific user from firebase authentication (Modular JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way I can get a specific user uid from firebase and then delete it?

```
import { deleteUser, getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
```

deleteUser(User) -> User object

How can i delete Specific user by uid using modular javascript?

Comment: It's not possible using any web or mobile frontend SDK, modular or not.  You can only delete a specific user from your backend using one of the [Admin SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user) or the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth) with an appropriate service account credential.  If you want to trigger it from your frontend, you'll have to build a backend endpoint and invoke it from your frontend, making sure that the person invoking it has permission to delete any user account.